# Hoverable menu to appear in different sections of page

Tags: menus

Basically I require my sub menu items to appear in different areas of the page when hovered. Please have a look at the link below:

http://brainstormmarketing.agency/dev/UBG/

There are FOUR main menu items. The sub menu items should be displayed in the FOUR blocks on the home page, namely, Print and Document Division, IT Division, Telcoms Division and Safety and Security Division. They should only appear when hovered over the main menu items (FOUR)

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context? I am seeing the main menu working(https://cl.ly/070Q27290r3A) but I think you may be referencing the pieces of the homepage below that are also labeled "print and document..." etc. Do you want the sub-menu items to appear when the user hovers over those blocks that are further down the page?

Comment: Yes you are correct. When the user hovers over the FOUR main menu items, the sub menus would appear further down in the FOUR blocks. So it would appear in two places, 1) The main menu 2) Homepage blocks ... This is requested by our client but is obviously a unique request.

Comment: We are currently using a mega menu plugin called "Mega Menu"

Comment: To be clear, when a user hovers over "Telecoms Division" you want the sub-menu to appear inside the hovering menu, correct? The same with the rest of the blocks as well. If so I can submit an answer that would do the trick.

Comment: 100% correct. When the user hovers over "Telecoms Division" , the sub menus should appear in the block called "Telecoms Division" ... The same with the rest of the blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bradley,

Thank you for the additional clarification in the comments. I have written some javascript (jQuery) that you'll need to insert into your theme:

```
jQuery( "#panel-2-1-0-0" ).hover( //Print and Document
    function() {
        jQuery('#mega-menu-item-475').addClass('mega-toggle-on');
    }, function() {
        jQuery('#mega-menu-item-475').removeClass('mega-toggle-on');
    }
);

jQuery( "#panel-2-1-1-0" ).hover( //Telecom
    function() {
        jQuery('#mega-menu-item-477').addClass('mega-toggle-on');
    }, function() {
        jQuery('#mega-menu-item-477').removeClass('mega-toggle-on');
    }
);

jQuery( "#panel-2-1-0-1" ).hover( //IT Dev
    function() {
        jQuery('#mega-menu-item-476').addClass('mega-toggle-on');
    }, function() {
        jQuery('#mega-menu-item-476').removeClass('mega-toggle-on');
    }
);

jQuery( "#panel-2-1-1-1" ).hover( // Safety and Security
    function() {
        jQuery('#mega-menu-item-478').addClass('mega-toggle-on');
    }, function() {
        jQuery('#mega-menu-item-478').removeClass('mega-toggle-on');
    }
);
```

Each of these blocks targets the panel in question. Once the user hovers over a block, it finds the corresponding mega-menu element and applies a class which makes it display. When the user moves their mouse away, it removes the class and hides the menu.

As you see, the code is based on the ID's associated with the mega menu elements and the blocks. **If you change the blocks or menu ID's the script will no longer work.**

There is a cleaner way to accomplish this (not relying on the IDs) but for purposes of getting you headed in the right direction this will work.

Hope this helps get you on the right track and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Tom. I will try this shortly and revert if there are any further issues.

Comment: Hi Tom, unfortunately this script is not loading in Wordpress. I have used <script type="text/javascript"
   src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/js/menu-hover.js"></script>  in the footer on my functions.php page and 
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?> in the <head> of the functions.php file

Comment: @Bradley Can you edit your question and post the functions.php area where you are activating the script? I can debug better if I see how you are activating it. From what I see now on the site I can't find your menu-hover.js file, so I don't think it's appearing. Also you have javascript errors from another file, custom.js, that you can see here: https://cl.ly/2N0h3f2w3L1d